# CoffeeScript send hashed params to constructor

Tags: coffeescript

I want to create objects in Ruby style with CoffeeScript. So I want to do something like

```
class A
  constructor: (@params) ->

a = new A {send: true, name: "fit"}
a.send #true
```

Is there any "standard" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it directly.  You could define a base class that has code to do it, like such

```
class Base
   constructor: (props) ->
      for key, value of props
           @[key] = value


class Extend extends Base
    constructor: (props) ->
       super props
       alert "#{@key1}, #{@key2}"


e = new Extend 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'


alert "#{e.key1}, #{e.key2}"
```

[See it working here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%0Aclass%20Base%0A%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28props%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20key,%20value%20of%20props%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20@%5Bkey%5D%20=%20value%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Extend%20extends%20Base%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28props%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%20props%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%22#%7B@key1%7D,%20#%7B@key2%7D%22%0A%0A%0Ae%20=%20new%20Extend%20%27key1%27%3a%20%27val1%27,%20%27key2%27%3a%20%27val2%27%0A%0A%0Aalert%20%22#%7Be.key1%7D,%20#%7Be.key2%7D%22)

Comment: I've thought about something like that, but I'm very new in CoffeeScript and so couldn't get the working solution. Thank you.